# Hidden notes in Beamer

Tags: beamer, notes, sidenotes

1) Is it possible to make hidden notes on `beamer`?

2) Is it possible to hide them at the presentation time, from the eyes of listeners, but keep them in front of the presenter's eye? I assume that is not possible with a typical presentation tool, like Acrobat Reader.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Christian. Thanks! I do not understand the superficial requirement for MWE, while I am asking clear questions about if some features of a system is present or not, and if yes what the name is.

Comment: @user25004: Superficial? No! You can't expect other users here to write a document for you from the start.

Comment: I think the question is perfectly fine because the user does not want anyone to "write a document", but wants to know if there is package and software to create "Power-Point-like" presentations.

Comment: @Christian, the point is not who does it. The point is that it is not necessary at all, for some problems, depending on the context.

Comment: @user25004: I've stated my opinion, you've got yours ;-)